# UIView animation curve slowdown using UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, core-animation

I'm trying to figure out how to change the speed of an animation while the animation is happening. 
Would appreciate any help.

For example, I have this object(image1) that I want to move from one end to another. I've already implemented `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut` to make the animation start fast and then slowdown at the end, the problem is that the change of speed, from fast to slow, is barely noticeable, could someone please help me figure out how make the end of the animation much slower than the default  `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut` here's an example of the code I am using.

```
UIImageView *image1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"theImage.png"]];

image1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 300, 50, 50);

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:  UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^(void) {
                     image1.frame = CGRectMake(700, 300, 50, 50);
                 }
                 completion:NULL];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can accomplish this by using a custom timing function (CAMediaTimingFunction), along with key frames (CAKeyframeAnimation), on the layer property (CALayer) of the image view.

Other important ideas you'll need to know is a Bezier Curve, values, key times, and control points.
The first thing you're going to want to do is configure the animation.  This example will bring an image view up fast, then slow down as it goes off the screen.

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.y"];
animation.duration             = 2;
animation.repeatCount          = 0;
animation.removedOnCompletion  = NO;
animation.autoreverses         = NO;
animation.fillMode             = kCAFillModeForwards;

NSMutableArray *values = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *timings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *keytimes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

This is the tricky part now.  These three arrays will later be added to the animation and work together to form the speed curve!  The first value to go into values will signify the start location.  Keep in mind, CALayers are grid system from 1 to 1.  So I want to place my imageView sitting on top of the center line.

```
[values addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.imageView.center.y]];
```

Timings is the hardest part to understand.  It has to do with the control points in a Bezier curve.  You can go into photoshop to get exact points or http://ciechanowski.me/blog/2014/02/18/drawing-bezier-curves/ to estimate points. But I found these points good for a better ease out...

```
[timings addObject:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithControlPoints:0.1 :0.34 :0.0 :0.0]];
[keytimes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0]];
```

This is the destination location.  (you want n-1 timing functions. N being number of values or keytimes. There should be n values and keytimes). I just chose off the screen somewhere

```
[values addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:-self.view.bounds.size.height]];
[keytimes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2]];

animation.values = values;
animation.timingFunctions = timings;
animation.keyTimes = keytimes;

[self.imageView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey@"Animate"];
```